# Validating form comaring two fields values

Tags: validation, laravel-8

I'm trying to find Laravel 8 documentation on how to validate comparing two fields to each other. I'm creating an app that allows creating matches from teams in a database table, using the create() method in the controller. I looked into Laravel #Validation, even #Custom Validation Rules, but I can't find anything when comparing the two fields.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'local_team' => 'required',
        'local_score' => 'required|numeric',
        'visitor_team' => 'required',
        'visitor_score' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);

    $score = new Score();
    $score->local_team = $request->local_team;
    $score->local_score = $request->local_score;
    $score->visitor_team = $request->visitor_team;
    $score->visitor_score = $request->visitor_score;
    $score->save();
    $new = true;

    return redirect()->route('scores.show', 
        ['id' => $score->id, 'new' => true]);
}
```

In my case, the 'local_team' and 'visitor_team' fields should be different. Any clue on how to do it?

Comment: Yes, check the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-different

Comment: Great, I'll try this solution. Thanks.